# How do I use css to set a background image using the cover property on a div, not the body?

Tags: css, background-image, background-position, cover

I have a div, .cover-section, that I want to have a full background image that is the size of the viewport.  I want to use the cover css property.  I have got this working for the body of the page, but if I add more content and try to scroll, the image stays as the background.  I want the image to scroll along with the content.  This is what I have so far:

```
.cover-section {
    background-image: url('../images/cover.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

How would I get it to do what I want?

Comment: If you want the image to scroll with the content, you probably don't want `background-attachment: fixed`. Generally, background image scrolling doesn't work unless the background is applied to the viewport - do you have a specific reason to apply it to a div instead of the body in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line
`background-attachment: fixed;`